SearchCallback and FilterCallback Stack Overflow error
I am using DropDownMenu class.
I am getting Flutter Stack Overflow error.
I cannot figure out what's causing it.
Could you please help.
I would like to do search and filter:
DropdownMenu(enableFilter: true, filterCallback: mg1(filteredentries,filterquery),searchCallback: xp1(entries,query)

I defined search and filter functions as follows:
List myList=[];

  SearchCallback<String>? xp1(List<DropdownMenuEntry<Text>> entries, String query){
    if (query.isNotEmpty) {
      myList = entries.where((DropdownMenuEntry<Text> entry) => entry.label.toLowerCase().contains(query)).toList();
    }
    return xp1(entries,query);
  }

String trimmedFilter ='';
  List filteredList=[];

  FilterCallback<String>? mg1(List<DropdownMenuEntry<Text>> filteredentries,String filterquery){
    trimmedFilter = filterquery.trim().toLowerCase();
    filteredList = filteredentries.where((DropdownMenuEntry<Text> entry) => entry.label.toLowerCase().contains(trimmedFilter)).toList();
    return mg1(filteredentries,filterquery);
  }


Your xp1 and mg1 functions do not make sense and will end up recursively calling themselves in infinite loops (which then results in a stack overflow).

How would you change the code to return a function from SearchCallback and FilterCallback to avoid an infinite loop? Thank You

I dont know if I understood your point but follow a code working.
         DropdownMenu<Text>(
            enableSearch: true,
            enableFilter: true,
            searchCallback: (List<DropdownMenuEntry<Text>> entries, String query) {
              if (query.isEmpty) {
                return null;
              }

              myList = entries.where((DropdownMenuEntry<Text> entry) => entry.label.toLowerCase().contains(query)).toList();
              print(myList.length);
              for(int i=0;i< myList.length-1;i++){
                 print(myList[i].toString());
              }

              final int index = entries.indexWhere((DropdownMenuEntry<Text> entry) => entry.label == query);

              return index != -1 ? index : null;
            },
            filterCallback:  (List<DropdownMenuEntry<Text>> entries, String filter) {
              final String trimmedFilter = filter.trim().toLowerCase();
              if (trimmedFilter.isEmpty) {
                return entries;
              }

              return entries
                  .where((DropdownMenuEntry<Text> entry) =>
                  entry.label.toLowerCase().contains(trimmedFilter),
              )
                  .toList();
            },

            dropdownMenuEntries: ['x1','x2','x1','x4','x5'].map<DropdownMenuEntry<Text>>(
                  (String txt) {
                return DropdownMenuEntry<Text>(
                  value: Text(txt),
                  label: txt,
                );
              },
            ).toList(),
          ),

If you write "x" will print 5 elements and when you write "x1" for instance, will print two elements in list.
